# Error when running wireshark

Tags: wireshark

I get the following error when running wireshark.

```
sudo wireshark
```

error:

```
wireshark: symbol lookup error: wireshark: undefined symbol: wslua_plugins_get_descriptions
```

versions:

- ubuntu: 22.04
- wireshark: 3.6.2

Comment: Wireshark has many pages of support info, this might help you. https://www.wireshark.org/faq_plain.html

Comment: @guiverc installed wireshark with (sudo apt install wireshark)